# List in display not getting updated using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, arrays

```
<div class=container ng-controller="myController as m">
<label> Enter your task : </label>
<input type="text" id="textBox" />
<hr>
<input type="button" value="Add task to list" id="addButton" />
<input type="button" value="Delete task" id="deleteButton" />
<hr>
<h3>Tasks</h3>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="task in m.tasks"> {{task.taskname}} </li>
</ul>
```

This is the template code where I update list using `ng-repeat`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
    $scope.tasks = [];
    var addButton = document.getElementById("addButton");
    var delButton = document.getElementById("delButton");
    $scope.tasks.length = 0;
    addButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        debugger;
        if (document.getElementById("textBox").value.length > 0) {
            $scope.addTask(document.getElementById("textBox").value);
        }
    })
    $scope.addTask = function(item) {
        $scope.tasks.push({
            taskname: item
        });
    }
}])
```

Input from a textbox and on onClick event of button display to be updated by adding task. I have an array that updates when an input is given. When i check console, my array is updating but display doesnt get updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes

(i) Don't mix up jquery with angular use **`ng-click`** directive instead

(ii) If you are using $scope variable don't use controller as syntax. Either go with one approach.

(iii) Use **`ng-model`** for your input and add it to your array.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp =angular.module('myApp',[])
myApp.controller('myController',['$scope','$log',function($scope,$log)
{
    $scope.task ='';
    $scope.tasks=[];     
    $scope.addTask=function(item)
     {
         $scope.tasks.push({taskname:item});
     }

}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" class=container ng-controller="myController">
          <label> Enter your task : </label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="task" id="textBox"/>
            <hr>

            <input type="button" ng-click="addTask(task)"  value="Add task to list" id="addButton" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete task" id="deleteButton"/>
            <hr>
            <h3>Tasks</h3>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="task in tasks"> 
                    {{task.taskname}} 
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Comment: Okay. I did changes to include ng-model and corresponding code but kept the jquery part as it is. It did not work. Can you tell why? And your solution worked. Thanks but i want to know the reason for above mentioned too.

Comment: @ManasaN. as i explained earlier you do not need jquery here. check the demo

Answer (score -1):

Please find following code changes, I am not seeing any use of delete button here, it should be available per item.

HTML

```
 <div ng-app>
 <div class=container ng-controller="myController">
          <label> Enter your task : </label>
          <input type="text" id="textBox" ng-model="task"/>
            <hr>

            <input type="button" value="Add task to list" id="addButton" ng-click="addTask()"/>
            <input type="button" value="Delete task" id="deleteButton"/>
            <hr>
            <h3>Tasks</h3>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="task in tasks"> 
                    {{task.taskname}} 
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
       </div>
```

JS

```
function myController($scope){
    $scope.tasks=[];
    $scope.task = ""
    var addButton=document.getElementById("addButton");
    var delButton=document.getElementById("delButton");
    $scope.tasks.length=0;
    $scope.addTask=function(){
                    console.log($scope.task)
            $scope.tasks.push({taskname:$scope.task});
            $scope.task = ""
        }

}
```

Comment: I would like to hear comments here instead of -1, as far as I think my solution works fine.